# issue with table to store files for multiple other tables

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-3.0

## What I'm trying to do:

I'm using [josegonzales/cakephp-upload](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload) to handle my upload by attaching an upload behaviour to a model called attachments. When I use the attachments add action there isn't any issue uploading a file but my goal is to upload a file with a hasMany relationship from Node. In The Future I'm planning to attach the AttachmentsTable to multiple other models like users for storing multiple user images.

## My Setup:

Database Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nodes` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attachments` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `foreign_key` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_dir` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_size` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

AttachmentsTable

```
class AttachmentsTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('attachments');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
            'file' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'dir' => 'file_dir', 
                    'size' => 'file_size',
                    'type' => 'file_type',
                ],
                'nameCallback' => function($data, $settings) {
                    $newName = uniqid() . str_replace(" ", "_", $data['name']);
                    return $newName;
                },
                'keepFilesOnDelete' => false,
                'pathProcessor' => 'Josegonzalez\Upload\File\Path\DefaultProcessor',
                'transformer' => 'BaseKit\Model\Table\FileTransformer',
                'writer' => 'BaseKit\Model\Table\FileWriter',      
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

NodesTable

```
class NodesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('nodes');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Attachments', [
            'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
            'conditions' => array('Attachments.model' => 'Nodes'),
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

Nodes add.ctp

```
<?= $this->Form->create($node, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Node') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('title');
            echo $this->Form->input('body');

            echo $this->Form->input('attachments.0.title');
            echo $this->Form->input('attachments.0.file', ['type' => 'file']);
            echo $this->Form->input('attachments.0.file_dir', ['type' => 'hidden']);
            echo $this->Form->input('attachments.0.file_type', ['type' => 'hidden']);
            echo $this->Form->input('attachments.0.file_size', ['type' => 'hidden']);
            echo $this->Form->input('attachments.0.model', ['value' => 'Nodes', 'type' => 'hidden']);
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

## The Issue:

When I'm trying to upload a File using the Nodes add.ctp the file wont be uploaded and the attached uploadbehaviour won't get used. The title and model field from attachment will be saved and the foreign_key also is correctly set.

Can somebody help me and explain why the behaviour of the related attachmenttable won't be used?
If theres a major issue with my approach, how would I achieve my goal on having a flexible upload table which I can attach to any model?

Comment: What is the problem to upload image using your own code ? Why are you using others code ?

Comment: because that plugins helps storing my data to multiple adapters of flysystem. Why should i write my own upload code if there are plenty of plugins available? My Issue is not about uploading a file, i want to understand why the behaviour is not executed..